# Default div to show until changed by user via selector

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs that show different information. Using a dropdown you can choose the div you want to show. I have this working but I can't show the default div on load. Also, I use a cookie to store the div selection

I tried adding the default `show-gmt` to the div but it would always show even when other divs were chosen

> The selector code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="gmt-select">
            <select id="song-gmt-selector" class="tooltip" title="Toggle track 
                  info">
                <option value="genres" title="Show Track 
                  Genres">Genre</option>
                <option value="moods" title="Show Track Moods">Mood</option>
                <option value="themes" title="Show Track 
                   Themes">Theme</option>
                <option value="instruments" title="Show Track 
                   Instruments">Instru</option>
                <option value="info" title="Show Track 
                  Description">Desc</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> The Div Code:

```
<div class="box genres_s"></div>
<div class="box moods_s"></div>
<div class="box desc_s"></div>
```

> The Jquery Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var current = '';
        $('#song-gmt-selector').on('change', function () {
            current = $(this).val();

            $('.box').removeClass('show-gmt');
            $('.' + current + '_s').addClass('show-gmt');
            localStorage.setItem('current', current);
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('current'));
        });
        if (localStorage.getItem('current')) {
            $('#song-gmt-selector').val(localStorage.getItem('current'));
            $('.' + localStorage.getItem('current') + '_s').addClass('show-gmt');
  }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi check the edited code i guess this will work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you are looking for something like this right ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width='device-width', initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .box {
            display: none;
        }

        .show-gmt {
            display: block !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="gmt-select">
                <select id="song-gmt-selector" class="tooltip" title="Toggle track 
                      info">
                    <option value="genres" title="Show Track 
                      Genres">Genre</option>
                    <option value="moods" title="Show Track Moods">Mood</option>
                    <option value="themes" title="Show Track 
                       Themes">Theme</option>
                    <option value="instruments" title="Show Track 
                       Instruments">Instru</option>
                    <option value="info" title="Show Track 
                      Description">Desc</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="box genres_s">genres_s</div>
    <div class="box moods_s">moods_s</div>
    <div class="box desc_s">desc_s</div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var current = '';
        if (!(localStorage.getItem('current'))) {
            current = $('#song-gmt-selector').val();
            $('.box').removeClass('show-gmt');
            $('.' + current + '_s').addClass('show-gmt');
            localStorage.setItem('current', current);
        }
        $('#song-gmt-selector').on('change', function () {
            current = $(this).val();

            $('.box').removeClass('show-gmt');
            $('.' + current + '_s').addClass('show-gmt');
            localStorage.setItem('current', current);
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('current'));
        });
        if (localStorage.getItem('current')) {
            $('#song-gmt-selector').val(localStorage.getItem('current'));
            $('.' + localStorage.getItem('current') + '_s').addClass('show-gmt');
        }
    });
</script>

</html>
```

I hope this helped

Comment: This is what I have already. The code I have works to show and store a div but the only issue is I can't show a div on initial load.. So I need the genres to show as default untill user changes to show another div

Comment: Amazing! Could you possibly explain the part that fixed the issue? Oh i see its the top if?

Comment: Check out the first if condition, where I'm just checking that local storage, is having any value with that key? If no it means it is an initial load so I take the value of the currently selected in <option> and did the same thing which you have done on the change event of the select

Comment: Great. Work very nicely

Comment: Please vote up and flag the comment if you understood...Thanks